# Concat on one-to-many when joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

*Hosts:*

```
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
| id | name |   url   | environment | instanceId | region |      created_at       |      updated_at       | value |
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|  4 | test | testing | qa          |  foo       |  bar   | "2017-09-23 14:57:18" | "2017-09-23 14:57:18" |  1222 |
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+
```

*ddframes:*

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | value | owner |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |  1222 |     4 |
|  2 |   333 |     4 |
|  3 |   444 |     4 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

`owner` on ddframes is a foreign key of `id` on `hosts`

My desired output is:

```
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| id | name |   url   | environment | instanceId | region |      created_at       |      updated_at       |   ddframes   |
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
|  4 | test | testing | qa          | hiri       | sdf    | "2017-09-23 14:57:18" | "2017-09-23 14:57:18" | 1222,333,444 |
+----+------+---------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

Where the ddframes are concatenated together.

What I have is:

```
SELECT h.*, d.value as ddframes
FROM hosts h
INNER JOIN ddframes d
ON h.id = d.owner
GROUP BY h.id;
```

But it produces something similar to my desired output just without the other ddframes. Only the first one.

Is that achievable? Maybe my tables' design is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `group_concat()` function:

```
SELECT h.*, GROUP_CONCAT(d.value) as ddframes
FROM hosts h INNER JOIN
     ddframes d
     ON h.id = d.owner
GROUP BY h.id;
```

I should note.  In general, it is a bad idea to have `SELECT *` in a `GROUP BY` query.  Assuming that `hosts.id` is unique (which the primary key is), then this is acceptable.  In fact, the ANSI standard supports this construct for unique keys in the `GROUP BY`.